# Phylogenetic tree of fragments of the same protein (from a metagenome)

Tags: bioinformatics

OK, I have several hundred fragments of a protein of interest(699 sequences) that I would like to align and make a neighbor joining tree of. These fragments do not in many cases align well to one another (different regions of the same or similar proteins). However, whole protein sequence(s) have been defined and submitted to NCBI and other databases etc. There are also trees made in literature for these proteins. Is there a way to take my fragments from my metagenome, and align them to the known sequences to define where each of my fragments lie on the published tree? 
my only solution to this is to run each sequence (or cluster of sequences) on the predefined tree (using the original whole protein sequences from publication) so as to define where each fragment would lie. IS there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You should probably support this: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6729/bioinformatics ; in the meantime you may find help at http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Probably the better place to ask this question is here: http://biostar.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well the alignment tool [Clustal](http://clustal.org) makes alignments and can also, with the proper flags, make trees. I believe that if you create a fasta file with the all the sequences in it including the largest one metagenome. It can make you automatically produce phylogenic trees based on the alignment scores. I am unsure if this accomplishes everything you desire, but it is a start. You may have to creat several .fasta files to align using some intelligent design and prior knowledge to produce the desired results. Here is a Perl script I wrote that makes alignments and phylogenic trees:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 


use warnings;

print "Please type the list file name of protein fasta files to align (end the directory   path with a / or this will fail!): ";
$directory = <STDIN>;
chomp $directory;

opendir (DIR,$directory) or die $!;

my @file = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

my $add="_align.fasta";

foreach $file (@file) {
 my $infile = "$directory$file";
 (my $fileprefix = $infile) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
 my $outfile="$fileprefix$add";
 system "/Users/Wes/Desktop/eggNOG_files/clustalw-2.1-macosx/clustalw2 -INFILE=$infile -OUTFILE=$outfile -OUTPUT=FASTA -tree";
}
```